# Hand over either all or specific columns as parameter in a function with dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from IPython.display import display

# Create a list of datetime values with 1-minute intervals for 5-6 rows
date_list = [datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(5, 11)]

# Create a DataFrame with the datetime column and two integer columns
data = {
    'bucket': date_list,
    'ophPumping': [1, 2, 3, 30, 20, 5],
    'ophNonPumping': [1, 2, 3, 20, 4, 5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the 'bucket' column as the index
df.set_index('bucket', inplace=True)


# Remove invalid data
df = df.dropna()
outliers = pd.DataFrame()

# Worked with a specific column given
def find_outliers(df, columns:str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    start = df.shape[0]
    while (True):    
        df['DifferencePumping'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ophPumping'].diff(), unit="h")
        df['DifferencePumpingShifted'] = df['DifferencePumping'].shift(-1)
        df['bucket'] = df.index

        df['DifferenceBucket'] = df["bucket"].diff()
        df['DifferenceBucketShifted'] = df['DifferenceBucket'].shift(-1)
    
        df["decreasing"] = df["DifferencePumping"] < pd.Timedelta(0)
        df["rapid_increase"] = df["DifferenceBucketShifted"] > df["DifferencePumpingShifted"] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=6)

        df["potential_outliers"] = df.decreasing | df.rapid_increase   

        try:
            outliers = pd.concat([outliers, df.loc[df.potential_outliers].head(1)])
            df = df.drop(df.loc[df.potential_outliers].index[0])
        
        except IndexError as index_error:
            print("Filtered all outliers.")
            break

    # remove created columns, since they're not needed anymore
    df = df.drop(columns=['DifferencePumping', 'DifferencePumpingShifted', "bucket", "DifferenceBucket", "DifferenceBucketShifted", "decreasing", "rapid_increase", "potential_outliers"])

    display(df)
    print()
    print("Removed outliers:")
    display(outliers)
    print()
    print('Head of cleaned df')
    display(df.head(5))
    print()
    print(f"Deleted {start - df.shape[0]} rows.")
return df
```

And then I wish I could call the function with something like:

```
df = df.remove_outliers(df, all columns?)
```

I'd like to be able to set column as a parameter in where I can specify the column (here it's just simply df) or the function to run over all the columns that can be found in the df.
I tried unsuccesfully with a for loop, but yea.

Does anybody know?

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

def remove_outliers(data_frame, columns=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    if columns is None:
        # If columns are not specified, use all columns in the DataFrame
        columns = data_frame.columns.tolist()

    # Remove invalid data
    data_frame = data_frame.dropna(subset=columns)
    outliers = pd.DataFrame()

    start = data_frame.shape[0]
    while True:
        for column in columns:
            data_frame['DifferencePumping'] = pd.to_timedelta(data_frame[column].diff(), unit="h")
            data_frame['DifferencePumpingShifted'] = data_frame['DifferencePumping'].shift(-1)
            data_frame['Bucket'] = data_frame.index
            data_frame['DifferenceBucket'] = data_frame["Bucket"].diff()
            data_frame['DifferenceBucketShifted'] = data_frame['DifferenceBucket'].shift(-1)

            data_frame["decreasing"] = data_frame["DifferencePumping"] < pd.Timedelta(0)
            data_frame["rapid_increase"] = data_frame["DifferenceBucketShifted"] < data_frame["DifferencePumpingShifted"] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=6)

            data_frame["potential_outliers"] = data_frame.decreasing | data_frame.rapid_increase

            try:
                outliers = pd.concat([outliers, data_frame.loc[data_frame.potential_outliers].head(1)])
                data_frame = data_frame.drop(data_frame.loc[data_frame.potential_outliers].index[0])

            except IndexError as index_error:
                print("Filtered all outliers.")
                break

        # remove created columns, since they're not needed anymore
        data_frame = data_frame.drop(columns=['DifferencePumping', 'DifferencePumpingShifted', "Bucket", "DifferenceBucket", "DifferenceBucketShifted", "decreasing", "rapid_increase", "potential_outliers"])

        display(data_frame)
        print()
        print("Removed outliers:")
        display(outliers)
        print()
        print('Head of cleaned df')
        display(data_frame.head(5))
        print()
        print(f"Deleted {start - data_frame.shape[0]} rows.")

        return data_frame
```

I tried it with a for-loop - but then sadly it didn't remove the correct outliers

Comment: Could you post a sample input and what the expected output would be so we can know what the expected outliers are?

Comment: Also, try to simplify your code to reduce it to the minimal reproducible part, remove all the non necessary parts.

Comment: @Jesse Sealand For example, I expect the Code to run trough a column like 'ophPumping': [1, 2, 3, 30, 20, 5] and to detect the outliers 30 and 20. 
In my head it makes sense to do this comparison: 
`data_frame["rapid_increase"] = data_frame["DifferenceBucketShifted"] < data_frame["DifferencePumpingShifted"] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=6)`

But it's sadly not removing the outliers. 
Does anybody of you see why it's not working?
Other than that, If I use a much much bigger dataframe that I cannot share, it's working with the same comparison - but I don't know why :/

Comment: @mozway if I could've simplified it, I would've done it already, I'm sorry :(